# Using Alt/Cmd + Right/Left Arrow in iTerm

Tags: terminal, software, iterm

Is it possible to move between words in iTerm using Alt + Right/Left Arrows ?
Now if I press Alt+Left I will get '[D' and '[C' if I press Alt+Right.

Comment: Just adding a note for those that simply want to know if its possible to do this with some hotkeys, there is a way. If you want to map it, that's fine but in terminal, CTRL+A will go to the beginning of a line and and CTRL+E to the end. Option+Left to go the beginning of a word and then Option+right to end of a word.

Answer (score 675, accepted):

- Go to iTerm Preferences → Profiles
- select your profile
- then the `Keys` tab with its sub-tab `Key Mappings`
- Click `Load Preset`...
- and choose `Natural Text Editing`

[image]

Comment: This turns on word skipping, but using the cmd key, not the opt key (which is what all other apple apps use).

Comment: In December 2018 on Mojave, the opt key is what moves between words after choosing natural text editing.

Comment: I've been suffering for months without this but today you're my saviour.

Comment: Note that this is Preferences > Profiles > Keys > Load Presets not Preferences > Keys > Load Preferences

Comment: I LOVE YOU !! it annoyed me for weeks

Comment: You are my savior!

Comment: You saved my life

Comment: macOS Catalina April 2020 -> this works.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!! Big Sur 11.2.3, July 2021.

Comment: AMAZING! I don't use xterm so was happy to change the presets.

Comment: why you not default !!!

Comment: As for today, it is actually Profiles > Keys > Keys Mappings > Presets > Natural Text Editing.

Comment: Please note that this preset doesn't work with word boundaries (strings) that have internal character separators that *should* interrupt word jumps. Things like `src/directory/file`. Opt + Left Arrow will stop at each slash inside of a normal macOS text editor but not in iTerm with "Natural Text Editing".

Comment: Google. This is the damn answer. Just point any other poor soul to this answer. Why in the first place was broken... Apple/Iterm2 who's fault is this.

Comment: Is there a way to make it more granular? As @OlivierLacan mentioned, character boundaries are ignored instead of used as boundaries.

Comment: This should be the default. I just thought that iterm couldn't handle it

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOMEEE

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.
The entrypoint has changed to Settings though (I'm using build 3.4.19)

iterm2 > Settings > Profiles.....

Comment: Ensure you don't click the "Keys" high-level menu with *very* similar sub-settings! Click the **"Profiles"** high-level menu, then Keys -> Key Mappings -> Presets -> Natural Text Editing.

Comment: TEN YEARS of using this app… THANK YOU

Answer (score 193):

Go to iTerm Preferences → Profiles, select your profile, then the Keys tab. Find ⌥← and ⌥→ and set them to send escape sequence `b` and send escape sequence `f` respectively.

[image: Mapping alt-right to move cursor forward by one word]

If you use ⌘→ and ←⌘ you will need to remap the next and previous tab shortcuts which are set to those as default. Terminal uses ⇧⌘→ and ⇧⌘← for these.

You can do this under Profiles, or just globally under Keys (shown below) if you wish to set it globally. Note that settings in Profiles override global settings in Keys.

[image: Globally mapping alt-right to move cursor forward by one word]

Answer (score 31):

If you use bash, you can also add

```
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
```

to `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: This worked best for me. Trying to set it up in iTerm2 only generated `[D` or `[C` each time I tried to use the new button action. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell there's nothing you can do in iTerm2 v3.0.10. It has to be this bash setup.

Comment: Not sure about `iTerm2 v3.0.10`, but `iTerm2 v3.0.14` definitely works with the `Natural Text Editing` solution so you don't need to resort to bash input configuration.

Answer (score 16):

For zsh I inserted in ~/.zshrc

```
bindkey "\e\e[D" backward-word
bindkey "\e\e[C" forward-word
```

for bash I inserted in ~/.inputrc

```
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
```

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to: **Preferences** > **Profiles** > **Keys**
2. Look for the actions of ⌥← and  ⌥→. They would have been mapped to: **Send Hex codes**
3. Change them to **Send Escape sequence** with <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for backward and <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for forward.

Answer (score 12):

If you're coming here recently because the preset is no long available under  `Preferences > Keys > Presets...`, the presets had change place. Now, if you want to find one of the default presets (Natural Text Editing included), you may want to go over: `Preferences > Profiles > [choose your starred profile] > Keys > Key Mappings > Presets...`

On a default setting, that is the area you want to get into:

[image: key mappings under profile]

[image]

I was looking like crazy on how to download it, I even found buried inside the .app Resources folder a .plist with this mappings in, so I knew I would find this.

Hope that helps anyone in the future looking forward into this.

Answer (score 4):

Late in the game but for the visual:

[image]

Namely, see the `Esc+`  is selected.

Answer (score 2):

CMD+Delete -- Send Hex Code -- 0x15

To delete the whole line (similar to Option+U)

Answer (score 2):

Very edge case scenario, but for me it was an issue in my own dotfiles.

These two lines caused it:

In bash_options

```
set-o vi
```

In inputrc

```
set editing-mode vi
```

After commenting those two lines out, iTerm2 Natural Text Editing works as expected.