# Run zsh alias via automator?

Tags: terminal, bash, automator, iterm, zsh

I am using zsh with oh-my-zsh in iTerm on macOS. There are some aliases defined in my .zshrc I use often, like this:

```
deploy(){
 cd ~/Path/To/My/Project;
 build ...;
 rsync ...;
}
```

To execute this, I have to switch over to iTerm and run the alias.
Now I'd like to be able to do that from anywhere via a hotkey.

I've read that automator is the tool of choice.

I created an action "run shell script" and chose `/bin/zsh/' from the list of available shells.

But running my alias returns `zsh:1: command not found`.

Am I on the wrong shell? But `echo $0` in iTerm gives me `-zsh`.

How can I run my alias without being in the iTerm window? Any approach will do, Automator is just how I'm trying to accomplish it.

Comment: Well, that is a function. Normally, you would write the function in a separate file and place it in a directory defined by `fpath`. In your `.zshrc` you would `autoload` the function in order to use it.

Comment: Oh! And then it would be available in all shells & automator, I guess. Would you say https://coderwall.com/p/ktv3hq/zsh-autoloading-functions-i which came up after following your hint would be correct?

Comment: What do you get from `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: `echo $SHELL` returns  /bin/zsh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to source the file dependencies you need inside the automator script.

Example if you added all of your scripts to `~/.zshrc`

```
source ~/.zshrc
deploy
```

You can debug things easier by doing `which deploy` to check to see if that script is accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Automator runs in its own environment and does not read your shell rc files. The PATH is limited to `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. None of the environment is exported for further use. You could define the function in Run Shell Script and run it like this:

```
 deploy () {
 cd ~/Path/To/My/Project;
 build ...;
 rsync ...;
 }

 deploy
```

Though this is somewhat limited.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.  But I have several functions, e.g. for build and rsync. Can they be "nested" in Run Shell Script?

Comment: @Urs Function definitions must precede their first call. Assuming that you are doing so in your script, I see no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround without automator;

On https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136931/60854 I read about hotkeys in iTerm. I made a hotkey in Keys > Hotkey to call iTerm to the foreground and another one in Profile > Keys > Key Mappings to enter a string `deploy\n`. Now I press `cmd-i cmd-o` and here we go.