# Shortcut to move one character iterm2

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut, iterm

How to move the cursor one character forward in iterm2? I can move one character backward with ^b. I tried ^f but instead of moving one character forward, it scroll through command history from the beginning.

Comment: Try this path: go to iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> *Default -> Load Preset... in the right pane, click on it and select either "Terminal.app compatibility" or "Natural Text Editing" preset keys. For me ^f works as needed. (does ^f works for you in Terminal.app?)

Comment: No, it does not work in Terminal.app either. Any suggestions where to change this settings? I tried to change Load Preset in iTerm2 but it behaves the same.

Comment: See this for more info: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136928/using-alt-cmd-right-left-arrow-in-iterm

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by going to `Preferences > Profiles`

Then, on the right hand side of the page, click on  the `Keys` tab and then on the `Load Preset` dropdown box. Then select `Natural Text Editing`.

Hope this helps.